# What should be the query to set an attribute of 'NOT NULL' on a column in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, insert-update, notnull

I've a table titled `'user'` in MySQL database.

It has a field titled `'full_name'`(varchar(255)). I want to set `'NOT NULL'` attribute to this column and update the column with value `'Dummy User'` where `'full_name'` column contains blank value.

So my question is how should I achieve both these things in one single update query?

The query I tried is as below but it gave me error:

```
ALTER TABLE `user` MODIFY COLUMN full_name NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Dummy User' WHERE full_name = '';
```

Please somebody help me.

Comment: Just to confirm, when you say *"column contains blank value"*, do you mean blank, or do you mean null? Also, any reason that this has to be a single query?

Comment: @GarethD: When I said "column contains blank value" I mean blank and 'NOT NULL'. You can give two queries, no issues.

Comment: Think there is no way. See the alter table syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html

Comment: Please review the answer given below.

Answer (score 1):

As the noble @jens pointed out in his comment, there is no way to alter the type of the `full_name` column to `NOT NULL` *and* also replace the empty strings with a default value in a single query.

The first query below changes the `full_name` column type to `NOT NULL` and sets the default column value to `Dummy User`. It *also* will replace all already-existing `NULL` entries with your desired default value. We are halfway done.  To cover the records which have empty string, I use a simple `UPDATE` statement.

```
ALTER TABLE users 
MODIFY COLUMN full_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Dummy User';

UPDATE users 
SET full_name = 'Dummy User' 
WHERE full_name = ''
```

Comment: Don't you think there should be where condition to update only those records where full_name field contains blank value?

Comment: I tried this query but it gave me error:
ALTER TABLE `user` MODIFY COLUMN full_name NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Dummy User' WHERE full_name = '';

Comment: Are you sure you have blank values in the `full_name` column, as opposed to just nulls?

Comment: yes, there are blank values, I mean nothing only blank space is there.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean an empty string and not some arbitrary amount of whitespace characters.